# How to use forASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

How can i use a button in my `a.asp` view to submit the button itself.

I tried like below, but I don't know how to pass the button as an parameter as there 's ajax calls, I want to use the button to submit a to the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var params = { 
            title: 'Hello' 
        }; 

        $("#button").live( "click", function () { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '<%= URL.Action("ajaxNew" , "Home") %>', 
                crossDomain: true, 
                data: { 
                    buttonId: $(this).attr("id"), 
                    buttonName: $(this).attr("name"), 
                    shareForm: $(this).parents("form").children("form").children("input.button"), 
                }, 
                error: function() { 
                    console.log(error); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data with a button,try to use `onclick`:

```
<button id="button" name="button" onclick="test(this)">button</button>
```

js:

```
function test(t) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%= URL.Action("ajaxNew" , "Home") %>',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    buttonId: $(t).attr("id"),
                    buttonName: $(t).attr("name"),
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
```

If you want to pass form data,you needs to get data from the form one by one,and put them into `data`.